# is this Promise to async convertion correct and why await is not necessary?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I've this snippet of code with a promise.

```
function f (number) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (number === 42) {
      resolve({ success : "bar" })
    }

    reject({ bar : "foo" })
  })
}

f(42)
  .then(success)
  .catch(bar);

f(43)
  .then(success)
  .catch(bar);

function success(input) {
  console.log(input)
}

function bar() {
  console.log("marianna")
}
```

and the following it the attempt to convert a promise to async/await syntax:

```
async function f (number) {
    if (number === 42) {
      return { success : "bar" }
    }

    throw { bar : "foo" }
}

f(42)
  .then(success)
  .catch(bar);

f(43)
  .then(success)
  .catch(bar);

function success(input) {
  console.log(input)
}

function bar() {
  console.log("marianna")
}
```

The output given from both scripts is equal. I think convertion is correct but I still got difficulties to "read" async code.

Anyway, .. why await is not necessary? When does await is required?

Comment: `await` is *never* required, you can always call `.then` on a `Promise`

Answer (score 1):

`await` can improve code reading. It treats `asynchronous` function call looks like `synchronous` call.

In your example, let's say if I want to run `f(43)` after `f(42)` finish. For this case, I can do like this below

```
f(42)
  .then(() => {
    success(); 
    return f(43);
  })
  .then(success) 
  .catch(bar);
```

comparing to `await`

```js
async function f (number) {
    if (number === 42) {
      return { success : "bar" }
    }

    throw { bar : "foo" }
}

async function run() {
  try {
    const result42 = await f(42); // async function but called like sync function
    success(result42); 
    
    const result43 = await f(43);
    success(result43);
  } catch(error) {
    bar(error);
  }
}

run();

function success(input) {
  console.log(input)
}

function bar() {
  console.log("marianna")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) is an object that represents an eventual completion or failure of an asynchronous operation.

There is nothing asynchronous in your code, both versions of function `f()` return a `Promise` that is already resolved or rejected. However, this does not change the way `async/await` works.

Using [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) your code should look like this:

```
async function f (number) {
    if (number === 42) {
      return { success : "bar" }
    }

    throw { bar : "foo" }
}

try {
    res = await f(42)
    success(res)
} catch(err) {
    bar(err);
}

try {
    res = await f(43)
    success(res)
} catch(err) {
    bar(err);
}

function success(input) {
  console.log(input)
}

function bar(err) {
  console.log(`error: ${err}`)
}
```

Behind the scenes, both versions of the code run the same way. But usually the `async`/`await` version is easier to read because the code is laid out the same way as synchronous code, with `await` in front of the asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

> I think conversion is correct but I still got difficulties to "read" async code.

I have 2 things I think about when deciding on `async/await` vs `then/catch` syntax:

1. Should it run on installations with NodeJS lower than version 7.6? If yes, we can only use Promise `then/catch` as `async/await` starts with v7.6 [NodeJS 7.6 support for async/await](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/node-76-async-await).
2. Which version would *read* cleaner to the next person maintaining my code?.

I use `async/await` when I think a section of code would **read cleaner as a sequence of procedures** in a `try/catch` block.

**async-await-test.js**

```js
main()

/* test body */
async function main() {
  try {
    const result = await pingMeAfterOneSecond(true)
    console.log('RESOLVED with ', result)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('REJECTED due to', e)
  }
}

/* some function that will resolve or reject as requested after 1 second -- this is same as in then-catch-test.js */
function pingMeAfterOneSecond(willSucceed) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (willSucceed) {
        resolve(true)
      } else {
        reject(false)
      }
    }, 1000)
  })
}
```

I use `then/catch` when I think a section of code would be **in danger of looking like a nested spaghetti of `try/catch` blocks**.

**then-catch-test.js**

```js
/* test body */
pingMeAfterOneSecond(true)
  .then(result => console.log('RESOLVED with ', result))
  .catch(e => console.log('REJECTED due to', e))

/* some function that will resolve or reject as requested after 1 second -- this is same as in try-catch-test.js */
function pingMeAfterOneSecond(willSucceed) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (willSucceed) {
        resolve(true)
      } else {
        reject(false)
      }
    }, 1000)
  })
}
```

Hope this helps you think through the choices. Cheers,